# How do I remove repeating symbol on user input example =======

Tags: php, regex

I want remove repeating character if more than 2 on user input, example

```
heloooo!!!!!!!!
====== hellloooo!!!!! ======
helooo!!!!! this is a 3 AAA battery holder
```

results should be

```
heloo!!
== helloo!! ==
heloo!! this is a 3 AAA battery holder
```

Let me know..

Comment: That would also change AAA in AA. ;)

Comment: So more than 2 'o' or '!' characters are not acceptable, but 'A' is? What is the criteria here?

Comment: @Entropy you right. Possible to keep it? or compare to reserve words which cannot be trim.

Comment: probably something like `preg_replace('/(.)\1{2,}/', '$1', ...)`, but that's reduce any repeated sequence to a single char.

Comment: I'm curious what your reserved words would look like... crosssection?  frillless?  governessship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$result = preg_replace('/([^\s\w])\1{2,}/', '\1\1', $subject);
```

This looks for a run of three or more identical characters (non-whitespace, non-alphanumeric) and replaces them with two of these characters.